# Does a 17 year old expat Israeli citizen need permission to visit Israel?

Tags: israel, israeli-citizens, military

A 17 year old boy that was born in Israel but left at a young age wants to visit Israel for the first time since leaving.  Does he need prior permission from the IDF (perhaps through the Israeli embassy in his country of residence) to make this trip to ensure being allowed to leave Israel without performing military service?

Comment: I think the close votes are because this seems to be more about military service than it is about travel.

Comment: Do you have an Israeli passport / Citizenship ? if so - than defiantly check you status with IDF .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are now of the drafting age you should probably resolve your Army status before attempting to visit Israel.

You can look at [this post on Expat Exchange](http://www.expatexchange.com/expat/index.cfm?frmid=230&tpcid=3356909) that seems to be specifically on point for your issue.

**EDIT**

Since there seems to be a question about the [Expat Exchange Post](http://www.expatexchange.com/expat/index.cfm?frmid=230&tpcid=3356909) here are a few more:

- http://idf-law.com/idf-army-status-faq/
- http://www.timesofisrael.com/canadian-israeli-detained-for-four-days-for-army-desertion/
- Similar as above but from 2009.  http://www.haaretz.com/idf-reneged-on-promise-not-to-arrest-deserter-couple-claims-1.281610
- http://972mag.com/idf-on-hunt-for-draft-dodgers-deserters/46443/

Comment: -1: That post appears to be by a law firm, trying to take advantage of people's uncertainty about their situation and scare them into hiring the firm to aid them.  The information in the post could be factual, I have no idea, but it would be nice to have a less biased source for it.

Comment: Based on this link it seems to have merit.  http://www.timesofisrael.com/family-of-detained-canadian-israeli-says-essentials-not-being-passed-to-her/

Comment: +1, because I canot see what's wrong with Karlson's answer ... short, simple and correct. Que demande le peuple?